# Create Java method in Servlet that sends Email to given Mail ID

Tags: java, email, servlets

Basically, I want to create Java method in Servlet that sends Email to given Mail ID.

For a bit detail, I am creating a online portal. Now, the feature I am implementing is that on user registration, a EMail will be sent to the registered EMail ID.
The situation is that I can't create a whole class or dedicated servlet to handle this operation. I need to create a dedicated method only and I can create other supportive methods and call them.

Please someone give me idea how to implement. I looked for it at 5-6 places but didn't understand code. It would be helpful if you explained the code too. I understand Java EE on Professional Level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read something about [JavaMail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html).

It implements necessary complexity for sending mail.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/), you have a good example in how to use it using Gmail SMTP service.

Let us know if you need some more help.